# elementary OS Juno - Wi-Fi always disabled after logging in

Tags: release-juno, internet

I'm new to Linux and I installed eOS [release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno) on my HP Spectre x360 yesterday.

Everytime I log-in to my account, the Wi-Fi is turned off and I have to toggle the switch. It's on after start-up BEFORE I log in, but after logging in, the airplane mode symbol pops up for a second and Wi-Fi is disabled.

But the airplane mode is never on when I check.

It's a minor problem, but if someone knows how I could fix this, I'd be glad. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hello do you have tlp installed?

If yes go to `/etc/default/` and edit file named `tlp`
there is this part:

```
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth wifi"
```

Which has wifi in it by default... that may be causing the problem.